# How to keep Multi page template PhoneGap?

Tags: jquery, css, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am new to Hybrid app, I am using PhoneGap, Jquery mobile in my Hybrid app, I have almost 10 separate pages like(login.html, index.html, search.html, etc..) in my app. My Question is that "Do I need to include all Js, css files in each page? or Just js and css files need to be included only in 1st app's page"?

The reason of the question is that I have noticed all the inner pages got all css and js from first page. Is It?

Comment: If you were to develop a mobile website or any other website, how you would use the css and js files, the same way you can use it in cordova, www folder. If you have different css and js for every page, my guess is that you have to include it in each page.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform a ajax load to load separate page, you don't need to put js,css reference in multiple pages.

For example:

```
<a href="multipage.html" rel="external" data-ajax='true'>Multi-page link</a>
```

Or dynamically

```
$.mobile.changePage( "multipage.html", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: false });
```

In this case no need to put references in all the files. multipage.html will contain only the body content.

But if you use a complete page load, like

```
window.location='multipage.html';
```

In this case, in the `multipage.html` file you to add js,css references once again.

Comment: Thanks your answer @AtanuCSE :), Why we need "ajax load"? what is the purpose of "Ajax load" ?

Comment: you need to read this page to get some idea. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/ see this `To enable animated page transitions, all links that point to an external page (ex. products.html) will be loaded via Ajax. ` there are different ways to load page in jquery mobile. read the link, it'll be clear to you.